# FSA for recognizing bit strings containing sequence "101!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

[image]

Hi, i was trying to write a FSA that recognizes the set of all bit strings that contain the string 101. Could this implementation be considered a correct one?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you know of any ways to prove  given FSA recognizes all and only strings with 101? I'm asking what acceptable methods of proof can be used.

Comment: It seems this doesn't accept 11101 since after that we're in state s1 which isn't a final state.

Comment: @coffeemath One could try to express with regular expressions the set of strings the FSA should recognize and list and by using the transitions defined one should show which transitions lead to acceptable strings?

Comment: Thanks for spotting an error

Comment: PwNzDust--- Can you look at my attempt to make such a FSA in my "answer" below? I'm new at doing them and woud like to know if I did it right. Also if you could draw what I did and add it into my answer I would appreciate it, since I don't know how to make such drawings.

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks, I will draw the FSA and check as soon as i can. In the meanwhile, the link to the editor is  the following: https://www.cs.unc.edu/~otternes/comp455/fsm_designer/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131087/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-pwnzdust).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: FSA diagram]

Here is a diagram of an FSA that I think does the job. On the arrow going from S2 back to S0 there should be a label of $0$ but now tht diagram is there I can't edit the diagram.

Comment: Thanks: I am quite sure this kind of implementation works fine